# Dotplot with two categorical variables and two quantitative variables

Tags: r, plot

I have a problem making a dotplot. I have a data frame "distribution_tab" with 4 columns and 6 rows. The two first columns are quantitative variables and the two other are categorical values :

```
     read.length     percentage.GC   strand     organism

1         203           63.0        forward     bacteria
2         250           33.0        forward     plant
3         205           72.0        reverse     bacteria
4         240           36.0        reverse     plant
5         210           33.5        forward     plant
6         230           63.5        reverse     bacteria
```

I want to make only one dotplot out of this data frame, with read.length in the x axis and percentage.GC in the y axis. The strand "forward" has to be represented with a dot and the strand reverse with a triangle (or with whatever two other different symbols). The organism "bacteria" has to be represented in pink and the organism "plant" in green.

So for instance, if one data is "forward and bacteria", it has to be represented with a pink dot in the dotplot, and if it is "reverse and plant" it has to be a green triangle.

I really don't know how to do this (or if it possible at all). For the moment I have made a dotplot with the two quantitative variables :

```
    plot(distribution_tab$read_length ~ distribution_tab$percentage.GC)
```

I have no idea how to distinguish them in the plot according to their organism and strand values.

Answer (score 3):

```
distribution_tab <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "read.length     percentage.GC   strand     organism
1         203           63.0        forward     bacteria
2         250           33.0        forward     plant
3         205           72.0        reverse     bacteria
4         240           36.0        reverse     plant
5         210           33.5        forward     plant
6         230           63.5        reverse     bacteria ")


plot(percentage.GC ~ read.length, data = distribution_tab,
     pch = c(17,19)[(strand %in% 'forward') + 1L],
     col = c('pink', 'green')[(organism %in% 'plant') + 1L])
```

[image]

or using `ifelse` but the above method is more flexible

```
plot(percentage.GC ~ read.length, data = distribution_tab,
     pch = ifelse(strand %in% 'forward', 19, 17),
     col = ifelse(organism %in% 'plant', 'green', 'pink'))
```

Comment: @zx8754 I'm just using the code that op has in the question

Comment: I am just quoting OP :)

Comment: @zx8754 does anyone really know what they want in life?

Answer (score 2):

Using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

df$col <- ifelse(df$organism == "bacteria", "pink", "green")
ggplot(df, aes(read.length, percentage.GC, shape = strand, col = col)) + 
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]
Data:

```
#dummy data
df <- read.table(text="     read.length     percentage.GC   strand     organism
                 1         203           63.0        forward     bacteria
                 2         250           33.0        forward     plant
                 3         205           72.0        reverse     bacteria
                 4         240           36.0        reverse     plant
                 5         210           33.5        forward     plant
                 6         230           63.5        reverse     bacteria ", header = TRUE)
```